# Keep track of which UITextField is currently in editing mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, inputaccessoryview

In the following code I have a couple buttons showing as an `inputAccessoryView` when `inputFieldOne` is in editing mode, when you tap `First Button`, it inputs `ONE` inside `inputFieldOne` and when I tap `Second Button` it inputs `TWO` inside `inputFieldOne`. It works as expected but what I would like to be able to do is re-use these buttons in multiple `UITextFields`. In other words, if I have another `UTTextField` called `inputFieldTwo`, I would like to be able to also input the values from those buttons when they're tapped.

How can I keep track of what `UITextField` is currently in editing mode so I can append the values from the buttons?

```
@IBOutlet weak var inputFieldOne: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var inputFieldTwo: UITextField!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    addButtonsToKeyboard()
}

func addButtonsToKeyboard(){
    // First button
    let button1 = UIButton()
    button1.setTitle("First Button", for: UIControl.State())
    button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonKeyPress), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    let barButton1 = UIBarButtonItem()
    barButton1.customView = button1

    // Second button
    let button2 = UIButton()
    button2.setTitle("Second Button", for: UIControl.State())
    button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonKeyPress), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    let barButton2 = UIBarButtonItem()
    barButton2.customView = button2

    /// UIToolbar.
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red

    toolBar.items = [barButton1, barButton2]
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    inputFieldOne.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}

@objc func buttonKeyPress(_ sender: UIButton){

    switch sender.currentTitle!{
    case "First Button":
        inputFieldOne.text = "ONE"
    case "Second Button":
        inputFieldOne.text = "TWO"
    default: break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to make it reusable as i have very limited time so i suggest you can do it  with **Extension**

You can use it for you all textfield

So here is the code snippet:

```
    extension UITextField
{
    // you can pass here array of UIbarbutton also
    func addButtonsToKeyboard(){
        // First button
        let button1 = UIButton()
        button1.setTitle("First Button", for: UIControl.State())
        button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonKeyPress), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        let barButton1 = UIBarButtonItem()
        barButton1.customView = button1

        // Second button
        let button2 = UIButton()
        button2.setTitle("Second Button", for: UIControl.State())
        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonKeyPress), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        let barButton2 = UIBarButtonItem()
        barButton2.customView = button2

        /// UIToolbar.
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red

        toolBar.items = [barButton1, barButton2]
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
    @objc func buttonKeyPress(_ sender: UIButton){

        switch sender.currentTitle!{
        case "First Button":
            self.text = "ONE"
        case "Second Button":
            self.text = "TWO"
        default: break
        }
    }

}
```

And with you textfield object you can add it with below code

```
txtSwift.addButtonsToKeyboard()
```

Hope it help you!!!